# How do I troubleshoot random rebooting?

Tags: windows, shutdown, reboot

For the past couple weeks, my PC has started having an issue where it randomly reboots. These reboots have happen 1-2 times a day, and have so far always been when I am away from it.

There isn't any discernible patterns I've seen from the reboot timestamps. I've thought it might be related to the power supply going bad, but it is fairly new. Also the fact that it is not rebooting under load, but rather while Idle, seems like it shouldn't be a PSU problem?

I also upgraded to Windows 10 the other day, expecting that to possibly affect/fix the issue, but it still happens regardless.

Here are the two events always generated by the reboot -

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlWkn.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gURa8.png]

[image]

Is there any way to further debug/troubleshoot what exactly is causing the reboots?

Comment: What are the full BSOD error messages? [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) should provide this information. Please [edit] your question to include this.

Comment: Hopefully I got the right information here, let me know if I need something else -

http://i.stack.imgur.com/MejXT.png


Couldn't put it in the main post, since I don't have the rep to post more than 2 links apparently?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be entirely honest, stop error `0x0000001a` is not good at all, as Windows has encountered a serious Memory Management error. I would suggest to start out by booting the [Memtestx86 CD](http://www.memtest.org/) to see if your RAM is bad.

Comment: Ran memory diagnostics on Windows, and it said something along the lines of "there is a hardware issue, contact the computer manufacturer". So, I guess that means it is for sure a memory problem?

Would Memtestx86 give me more information, like which stick of ram (there are 4) is actually having the problem?

Comment: @David indeed it does

Comment: Sorry, I tried to ninja-edit with my Memtest question, but you were too fast with the response.

Comment: @David heh, happens sometimes. Memtest would not but to be safe, I'd say replace all the RAM in one go

Comment: Alright, I've contacted Corsair, hopefully they'll be alright with replacing them all. It looks like they have lifetime warranty on memory modules.