# Windows 7 blue screen memory error bugcheck 0x0000001a

Tags: windows-7, memory

Here is my system specifications.

[image]

Error:

> The computer has rebooted from a bugcheck.  The bugcheck was:
>   0x0000001a (0x0000000000041790, 0xfffffa8003d23de0,
>   0x000000000000ffff, 0x0000000000000000). A dump was saved in:
>   C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP. Report Id: 080515-65988-01.

Log > http://pastebin.com/Btxxep58

Comment: You need to supply is either the memory dump itself or provide the relevant information from it  in order to help you analyze what the problem is.  [Here](http://superuser.com/questions/171196/how-to-analyze-a-memory-dump-on-windows-after-a-blue-screen-error?rq=1) is how you get starting getting the information we need.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the reply, here's the log: http://pastebin.com/Btxxep58

Comment: You just linked me to a .log file that contains that exact same information you already provided.  A linked you to information to get you started to analyze this problem on your own for a reason, by doing so, you will collect the require information required to help you.

Answer (score 2):

[bugcheck 0x0000001a](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) means `MEMORY_MANAGEMENT`. The important information come from the parameter 1.

0x41790 means this:

> A page table page has been corrupted. On a 64 bit version of Windows,
>   parameter 2 contains the address of the PFN for the corrupted page
>   table page. On a 32 bit version of Windows, parameter 2 contains a
>   pointer to the number of used PTEs, and parameter 3 contains the
>   number of used PTEs.

[According to Microsoft](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproperf/thread/68407ce1-7491-4aee-bdef-5ff4bbc56d99/#11ce9f45-7906-4652-9619-a3ad457a87e9), this is mostly caused by RAM (Hardware) issues:

> The 41790 code is part of our an internal memory manager code but the
>   bugcheck in my experience has almost always indicated hardware issues
>   (RAM errors).

So, run a memory test tool (memtest86+ or the internal Windows tool). Also check the RAM timings with [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) and look that the values from the `SPD` tab match to the data in the `memory` tab. If you have a `command rate` (CR) of 1, go to the BIOS and set it to 2. This can also trigger such BSODs.

Answer (score 0):

I literally just answered this [somewhere else](https://superuser.com/questions/951397/how-do-i-troubleshoot-random-rebooting/951407#951407).

To be entirely honest, stop error `0x0000001a` is not good at all, as Windows has encountered a serious Memory Management error. I would suggest to start out by booting the [Memtestx86 CD](http://www.memtest.org/) to see if your RAM is bad. Chances are it is, and to be safer, replace all RAM **at the same time**

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Ramhound how does it not? `0x0000001a` is a `MEMORY_MANAGEMENT` error, which is entirely related to this.

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557391(v=vs.85).aspx) says that but i wouldn't go by it without looking at crash dump as lot of weird stuffs happen these days with ;)

Comment: So the solution to his problem is to run Memtestx86?  If I had this problem, I would expect a little more help then that from an answer, then being told to just run Memtestx86.

Comment: @Ramhound I have edited it :P

Comment: I see nothing of any substance that would take a comment that basically would state the following: "these types of errors are connected to memory management errors and I have had success finding the culprit by running Memtestx86".  Don't get me wrong, I actually have a problem with the original  answer, but that has been accepted.  So it is hard to argue that it does not answer that user's question.